# How to create a function with parameters to find a specific object in a list of objects

Tags: c#, list

Im trying to create a function to finds all books that have the given author and returns a list of books. The function will accept a first and last name as parameters.

I have the function header that i must specifically use, and im unsure how to proceed further. Would appreciate some help

```
 public class Publisher
{
    #region Private Member Variables
    private String name;
    private List<Book> Books = new List<Book>();

    #endregion

    #region Properties
    [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
    public String Namee
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "Books")]
    public List<Book> Booking
    {
        get { return Books; }
        set { Books = value; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

   public Publisher() //default constructor
    {
        name = "Default Publisher";
        new Book();
    }

    Book FindBook(string title)
    {
        IEnumerable<Book> Query =
        (from x in Booking
         where x.Title == title
         select x);

        if (Query != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The book is: " + Query);
        }

        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

   List<Book> FindAllBooks(string first, string last)
    {
        List<Book> resultList = new List<Book>();

        foreach (Book x in Booking)
        {
            var authors = x.Arthur;

            foreach(Author c in authors)
            {
                if(c.First == first || c.Last == last)
                {
                    resultList.Add(x);
                }
            }
        }

        return resultList;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        foreach (Book item in Books)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        return "Publisher Name: " + name + "\n";
    }
    #endregion

}
```

}

Here is the class Book

```
public class Book
{
    #region Private Member Variables
    private string title;
    private List<Author> author = new List<Author>();
    
    private double price;

    #endregion


    public Book()
    {
        title = "mystory";
        /* author.First = "sam";
         author.Last = "Marty";
         author.Background = "default";*/
        
        new Author();
        price = 20;
    }

    #region Properties
     
    [DataMember(Name = "title")]
     public string Title
    {
        get { return title; } 
        set { title = value; }
    }

    //****************************************************
    // Method: Price
    //
    // Purpose: get set for price
    //**************************************************** 
    [DataMember(Name = "price")]
    public double Price
    {
        get { return price; }
        set { price = value; }
    }

    //****************************************************
    // Method: Arthur
    //
    // Purpose: get set for Author
    //**************************************************** 
    [DataMember(Name = "author")]
    public List<Author> Arthur
    {
        get { return author; }
        set { author = value; }
    }


    #endregion


    #region Methods
    //****************************************************
    // Method: ToString()
    //
    // Purpose: Output class contents of Book.cs
    //**************************************************** 
    public override string ToString()
    {

        foreach (Author item in author)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        return "Book Title = " + title + "\n" + "Book Author = " + "\n" + "Book Price =" + price + "\n" ;

        


    }
    #endregion


}
```

}

Comment: please show the class book

Comment: @pm100 Updated to show book class

Comment: Your `public override string ToString()` methods should do nothing other than return a `string`. They should not write to the `Console`. In fact, these objects are business objects so they probably shouldn't have anything to do with the `Console` anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this the straightforward way or the fancy way (LINQ). I suggest the straightforward way. Not going to write the code for you since this is clearly an assignment and you need to have a go.

```
create empty output list of books (result list)
for each Book in the list of books
   get author list
     for each author in author list
       if author first = first and author last = last add book to result list

return result list
```

make sure you use case insensitive match on author last and first

Comment: First off thanks so much. I Wanted to know if im on the right track. I updated my code n the original post. Also when you say get the author list from book. im unsure of what you mean by get.

Comment: @SirSoaponrope you have a function called 'arthur' on a book that returns the list of authors, call it (and maybe correct its name)

Comment: Its not letting me call it like a regular method. It says its a Non-Invokable Member. I may be calling it wrong. I updated the code to show you what im trying to do.

Comment: 'var authors = x.Arthur;'

Comment: You're the best. Thank you for not out right giving me the answer and challenging me. I added the final code to the original project. Is what i have okay?

Comment: i expect to see lat && first , not last || first, and what about case insenstive

Comment: at the moent you will match a book by john adams with the author john smith

Comment: Ahh you're right! Got it fixed! Thanks so much man!  @pm100